# Component not rendering when implementing useHistory from react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unclear as to why I am getting my URL to redirect but it's not rendering the corresponding component. I am referring to the `Result` component. I am not getting any errors, it is successfully unmounting `OnfidoSDK`, but it's not rendering my Result component.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import * as OnfidoSDK from 'onfido-sdk-ui/dist/onfido.min.js';
import 'onfido-sdk-ui/dist/style.css';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

const onfidoContainerId = 'onfido-sdk-wrapper';
const transmitAPI = 'third/party/api/url';

const useOnfidoFetch = (URL) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState();
  const [id, setId] = useState();

  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/post_stuff")
      .then((response) => response.data.data.data.json_data)
      .then((json_data) => {
        console.log("this is the json data", json_data);
        const id = json_data.applicant_id;
        const token = json_data.onfido_sdk_token;
        setId(id);
        setToken(token);
      });
  }, [URL]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) return;
    console.log("this is working!");
    onfidoOut = OnfidoSDK.init({
      token,
      containerId: "root",
      steps: [
        {
          type: "welcome",
          options: {
            title: "Open your new bank account",
          },
        },
        "document",
      ],
      onComplete: function (data) {
        console.log("everything is complete");
        console.log("this is the applicant id", id);
        let obj;
        axios
          .post("http://localhost:5000/post_id", {
            applicant_id: id,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            obj = response.data.data.data.json_data.result;
            onfidoOut.tearDown();
            handleRedirect();
          });

          function handleRedirect() {
            history.push('/result');
          }
      },
    });
  }, [id, token]);
};

export default function() {
  const URL = `${transmitAPI}/anonymous_invoke?aid=onfido_webapp`;
  const result = useOnfidoFetch(URL, {});

     return (
        <div id={onfidoContainerId} />
     )
}
```

I am not getting any errors in console. This is the `App.js` file with all of my components:

```
import Landing from './components/Landing';
import Onfido from './components/Onfido';
import Result from './components/Result';

export default () => {
   return (
      <div>
        <StylesProvider>
          <BrowserRouter>
           <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/onfido" component={Onfido} />
            <Route exact path="/result" component={Result} />
            <Route path="/" component={Landing} />
           </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </StylesProvider>
      </div>
   );
};
```

Now this is a microfrontend application. And in the `container` app inside of `src/components./MarketingApp.js`, I have is written in the following manner:

```
import { mount } from "marketing/MarketingApp";
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const { onParentNavigate } = mount(ref.current, {
      initialPath: history.location.pathname,
      onNavigate: ({ pathname: nextPathname }) => {
        const { pathname } = history.location;

        if (pathname !== nextPathname) {
          history.push(nextPathname);
        }
      },
    });

    history.listen(onParentNavigate);
  }, []);

  return <div ref={ref} />;
};
```

Since it's already using `useHistory` in the `container`, could that somehow be colliding with using `useHistory` on the sub app?

When I do a console log of `history` on the sub app, I get back an object with the property of `location`, `pathname: "/result"`

So on troubleshooting, I noticed that if I refresh the page, then the component renders. Not sure why that is though. Or could the issue be because I am rendering it in this manner:

```
import React from "react";

const onfidoHTML = `<h1>Thank You!</h1><H2>Your documents have been submitted for review.</h2>`;

export default function Result() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: onfidoHTML }} />;
}
```

I am properly using history, in my **container** app, there is a `src/bootstrap.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createMemoryHistory, createBrowserHistory} from 'history';
import App from './App';

const mount = (el, {onNavigate, defaultHistory, initialPath}) => {
  const history = defaultHistory || createMemoryHistory({
    initialEntries: [initialPath],
  });

  if (onNavigate) {
    history.listen(onNavigate);
  }
  
   ReactDOM.render(<App history={history} />, el);

   return {
      onParentNavigate({ pathname: nextPathname }) {
        const { pathname } = history.location;

        if (pathname !== nextPathname) {
          history.push(nextPathname);
        }
      },
   };
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
   const devRoot = document.querySelector('#_marketing-dev-root');

   if (devRoot) {
     mount(devRoot, {defaultHistory: createBrowserHistory()});
   }
}

export { mount };
```

Comment: @AjeetShah, `react-router-dom@5.2.0` I am getting `useHistory` from that library.

Comment: @AjeetShah, I do not, I never installed a package called `history`.

Comment: @AjeetShah, I am not using `Redirect`, I am using `history.push()` and it redirects to my url but not to its corresponding component, that being `Result`.

Comment: @AjeetShah, my apologies, I have been through so many refactors of this, my head is spinning. I corrected the OP.

Comment: Can you write `console.log(history)` in `handleRedirect` function and see if it prints a history object? Is it possible for you to create a codesandbox or git repo with minimal code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @AjeetShah, sorry I got really busy. It prints an object but not about history. So I do get back an object with a property of `location`, with `pathname: "/result"`.

Comment: @AjeetShah, I will try to get a github repo thrown together with an mvp in the next half hour or so.

Comment: @AjeetShah, okay just keep in mind there is one api request I cannot include well I cannot include the url because its internal and proprietary

Comment: @AjeetShah, So on troubleshooting, I noticed that if I refresh the page, then the component renders. Not sure why that is though, any ideas? Still working on getting you a repo.

Comment: @AjeetShah, here you are: https://github.com/ldco2016/poc